# How to get Sim number in android for api 22 to the top

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

**This my code but not working**

```
tManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phno);
           e3.setText(tManager.getLine1Number());
```

Comment: It is not work in above API 14.

Comment: Try checking in Phone--> Settings --> About --> Phone Identity, If you are able to view the Number there, the probability of getting the phone number from above code is higher. If you are not able to view the phone number in the settings, then you won't be able to get via this code!

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me

Inside onCreate

```
   Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
            btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    String CountryISO = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso().toString().toUpperCase();
                    String getSimSerialNumber = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
                    String getSimNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();


                    Log.e("Telephone Data : "getSimSerialNumber + "  " + getSimNumber);
                }
            });
```

Dont forget to add permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I have problem with getActivity()

Comment: in place of getActivity() call this

Comment: i know but i want use this in setOnClickListener

Comment: are you using it in activity ???

Comment: yes I want click on button and get sim number and show in edittext or textview

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: my problem with permission in manifest.READ_PHONE_STATE not working. i use targetSdkVersion 24